# Can 1 developer has 2 iTunes Connect account?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I am an iOS developer and I want to have 2 different iTunes Connect accounts, in order to submit apps in the first one, and games in the second one.

For example, my name is Fernando José Torres Sanz, can I have an account name Fernando Torres, and an account Jose Sanz?

Is it acceptable by Apple to 1 developer own 2 iTunes Connect account?

Answer (score 1):

If you own or control one or more legally incorporated entities, it appears that you can open a separate company iOS developer enrollment for each corporation, in addition to your own individual (non-company) developer enrollment.  You may need to use (one or more of) separate payment methods (credit cards), bank accounts, email addresses, and Apple IDs, for each separate paid enrollment

Comment: If I just only an individual developer, is it allowed by Apple? I have different credit card, bank account (same name, but different bank), Apple ID (just create other email)?

Comment: Reports are that it seems to be only one per person.   Read the developer agreement for more details.